# Get UILabel from UIView

Tags: ios, uilabel, subview

I have added a number of labels to a view giving them tags.

What is the correct way to retrieve a label from the view.  I am wanting to re-postion the label. Here is what I am using to retrieve the label and re-position it:

```
UILabel *theLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:5];
[theLabel.layer setPosition:CGPointMake(100, 200)];
```

Is this the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To **retrieve** the label, use an `IBOutlet` if you've created it in Interface Builder, or a raw property or ivar if created in code. There's no need to loop the subviews or use `viewWithTag` if you've got a direct reference (outlet, property, ivar) to it.

To **move** the label, directly set its `frame` or `center` property without needing to access its layer.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to go to the layer level, although it might work fine.

```
theLabel.center = CGPointMake(100,200);
```

I guess that does the same thing, without looking at the documentation to verify that a layer's default anchor point is its center.

Answer (score 1):

You can use fast enumeration with a for-loop:

```
for (UIView *view in [self.view subViews]) {
     if([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
          // do your stuff here
     }
}
```

Try this, it will surely work.

Comment: and it won't work if I have plenty of labels, they will all move together.

Comment: My favourite bit is `iskingOfClass` :)